# SPO 2013 - Visible item limit in the Site Feed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

We have the Site Feed on our intranet homepage but we thinkg it shows too many items as default. We would like for it to show only 5 items and then more when clicking the link at the bottom of the feed.

How can this be done? I've tried to search the internet for days and haven't found anything to help me solve this.

**EDIT:** Benny this is not a duplicate question as the answer in the other question doesn't really have an actual answer to this problem. I feel like the solution/answer can be accepted if it tells me a way I could somehow modify the site feed's visible item limit to 5 items or so with keeping the feed functionality and user experience the same. Now I already know it is not possible OOTB but that's why I'm asking for help in here if someone might know some other way to achieve the solution. ;-)

I'm very grateful for any solutions regarding this problem! Thanks! :-)

Comment: I feel that your question is a duplicate of the post that the duplicate post is marked a duplicate of. So maybe it should be closed as a duplicate of the latter post, but not the one that it is marked now?

Comment: @RobertLindgren, I checked the both posts in the "duplicate chain" and also the links & solutions that were offered and they just do not solve this problem even remotely close to what I'm asking. The given solution seems to be to make a list and use list views + pagination but that will alter that user experience and site feed functionality too much. We do not want a basic list but instead the site feed with just a fewer items visible above the "more posts" link or so. ;-)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, regarding if the answers are not: That's not up to us to judge. The questioner in the question that is now marked as duplicate is the same as yours (show me 5 a time instead of the default).

Comment: Ok so there is no way for me to seek help regarding this problem as long as the other person's similar, old and inactive question gets an answer or gets deleted/closed? :P

Comment: You can, and should start a bounty on the already existing question, that is the recommended way to drive attention to an old question :)

Comment: Roger that, I will keep monitoring the older question to see if it gets some answers.

Comment: I'm sorry that it feels like sub-optimal in this case, but the intention of this site is to never duplicate questions (to make all information regarding in issue easy to find in one location). Good luck to you!

Comment: Yep I understand that, no worries!